# Visual Studio 2010 Listing Class as 'Type Undefined" When MSDN states it Exists

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hopefully this will be one of those simple answers that is so simple they are hard to find through search (as most of my programing problems are these days)

I am currently attempting to create a VB.Net script that pulls up information on installed printers. I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, and as my target program needs to run on older machines, is currently built using .Net 3.5.

Looking online, there are several methods on how to do this, one from http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=148 uses the following code:

```
Dim oquery As System.Management.ObjectQuery = New System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer")

Dim mosearcher As System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher = New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery)

Dim moc As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection = mosearcher.Get()

For Each mo As ManagementObject In moc
Dim pdc As System.Management.PropertyDataCollection = mo.Properties

    For Each pd As System.Management.PropertyData In pdc
        If CBool(mo("Network")) Then
            cmbPrinters.Items.Add(mo(pd.Name))
        End If
    Next pd
Next mo
```

the code is supposed to use System.Management as you can see. However, after importing System.Management, Visual Studio throws an error and states that ObjectQuery, ManagementObjectSearcher, and ManagementObject are not defined.

a quick look at the MSDN forums [shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.objectquery.aspx) that ObjectQuery is a class of .Net 4, 3.5, 3.0 and 2.

I figured the error might be because I didn't have the .Net 3.5 SDK installed, so I installed the .Net 3.5 SP1 SDK to no avail.

edit: just to make clear, I am importing System.Management at the top "Imports System.Management"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check that your a reference to "System.Management" is correct. Make sure that the "System.Management.dll" is properly included and there's no warning triangle over the name.

[image: Open the references section]

[MSDN page for `System.Management.ObjectQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.objectquery(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: I've already imported System.Management and it gives the error. Sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: @somnia - sorry I missed that, but it would be worth double checking.

Comment: usually I'd agree. However I am using another class from System.Management for another function and it works fine. however the specific eludes me at this moment.

Comment: @somnia - an imports statement isn't the same as actually adding the reference. In the solution explorer open the References section and check there.

Comment: that was it. is there a quick link I can look at to learn the difference between using imports and adding a reference? eg when to use each? thx for the help.

Comment: @somnia - I don't know of a quick link but if you need to use a using/import statement then you need to add a reference.